# Wrap a nodeValue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to wrap a text in this code

```
<div class="div">
    <span></span>
    <a></a>
    *text I want to wrap*
    <span></span>
</div>
```

I know what the text is, but I can't know what is his position in the div

```
$(".div:contains('*text*')")
```

I get the right div like that, but I can't figure out how to wrap my text

Comment: With <a> but it doesn't matter as long as I know how to wrap it.

Comment: so what is your question? Give a http://jsfiddle.net/ will be better.

Comment: Can you show some of your existing HTML code?

Comment: I wanna have <a>*text I want to wrap*</a>

Comment: I think it's entirely clear from the example what he's trying to do. He wants `text I want to wrap` replaced by `<something>text I want to wrap</something>`, with the surrounding markup preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most simple method will be take the html of parent Element and replace the string with new string

```
newHtml = $(".div").html().replace("*text I want to wrap*","<b>new html</b>");
```

Now place back the new Html to The parent div

```
 $(".div").html(newHtml);
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/SFjRU/)

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption you want to wrap *all* text (I might be wrong, of course), I'd suggest:

```
$('.div').contents().each(
    function(){
        if (this.nodeType == 3) {
            $(this).wrap($('<a />', {'href':'#'}));
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zaR4a/3/).

If you want to wrap only *specific* text:

```
$('.div').contents().each(
    function(){
        if (this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.trim() == "*text I want to wrap*" ) {
            $(this).wrap($('<a />', {'href':'#'}));
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zaR4a/2/).

Given that you prefer the simple approach of treating HTML as a string, I thought I'd post a simpler answer than the one you accepted:

```
$('.div').html(
    function(i,h){
        return h.replace('*text I want to wrap*','<b>$&</b>');
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zaR4a/4/).

Comment: I tried this, and it works. But I choose the other one, because its simpler. Thank you anyway.